# nth-child selector not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to hide border from 4, 3, 2 wrapper based on the screen size.

I show 4, 3, 2 and 1 items in row based on screen size.

```
@media( min-width:1000px){
  #news-tab > div > .news-tab-item-wrapper:nth-child(2n+1){
   border-right:2px solid #fff;
   background:red;
  }
}
```

Based on above CSS it should not show border for the last element, but I am not able to target it. May be I am using wrong reference in this case.

```
<div id="news-tab" class="tab-pane">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="news-tab-item-wrapper"> 
      <span>This is News Title</span>
      <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="news-tab-item-wrapper"> 
      <span>This is News Title</span>
      <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="news-tab-item-wrapper"> 
      <span>This is News Title</span>
      <a href="#">Read More</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="news-tab-item-wrapper"> 
      <span>This is News Title</span>
      <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle Sample :http://jsfiddle.net/zvwqnwu2/5/

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zvwqnwu2/9/

Comment: May be use `:last` pseudoclass?

Comment: Can you provide working fiddle, so that I can see if the solution I gave works correctly? Of the top of my head it should, but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: Do you want this? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/zvwqnwu2/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in the code that is posted in question:

1. There is no element with `class` as `news-tab-item-wrapper-w`.
2. Even if the above is a typo, there is only one element with class as `news-tab-item-wrapper` also. The others have `news-tab-wrapper`.
3. If this was also a typo and all have the same class, the selector would still not work because each such item is the one and the only child to its parent.

For your case, I believe you need the below selector. This selector would select the element with `class` as `news-tab-item-wrapper` under a `div` element which is not the first child of its parent.

```
#news-tab > div:nth-child(n+2) > .news-tab-item-wrapper{
     border-right:2px solid blue;
     background:red;
}
```

---

If you want to target the last element with `.news-tab-item-wrapper` class then you could use either of the below selector for your current markup.

```
#news-tab > div:last-of-type > .news-tab-item-wrapper{
     border-right:2px solid blue;
     background:red;
}
```

or

```
#news-tab > div:last-child > .news-tab-item-wrapper{
     border-right:2px solid blue;
     background:red;
}
```

Comment: Sorry folks, Up date my question it had a type here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zvwqnwu2/4/ with the issue as i am not able to target 4th element when screen size is great then 600px let is say for example

Comment: @Learning: Do you want to target only the 4th element (or) only the last element?

Comment: @Learning: Could you clarify on the first few points mentioned in my answer please? What is the correct class name of the elements? Is your fiddle perfect?

Comment: Ok, now I understand that you wanted to select every 4th element. For that the `nth-child(4n)` should be apt.

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is an extra letter added so it is not affecting

remove `-w` from the class name

```
@media( min-width:1000px){
#news-tab > div > .news-tab-item-wrapper:nth-child(2n+1){
 border-right:2px solid #fff;
 background:red;
}
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zvwqnwu2/)**

Comment: In this case it is targeting 1 item not the last items

Answer (score 0):

".news-tab-item-wrapper" is first-child of "#news-tab > div"

also it is speled wrong .news-tab-item-wrapper **-w**:

try

```
#news-tab > div:nth-child(2n+1){
    //css here
    border-right:2px solid #fff;
    background:red;
}
```

and better aporoch would be to show border on first item than hide on all the rest for that you can use

```
 #news-tab > div:first-child{
      //add border
 }
```

Comment: -w is a typo mistake it is not there in actual markup.

Comment: I can't use first-child or last child as this is responsive page and it show 4, 3, 2 or 1 items on different screen.. I have to us nth-child to target this if i am not wrong..

Answer (score 0):

```
div > :nth-child(3)     the third child of a div element
div > :nth-child(even)  every even child of a div element
div > :nth-child(odd)   every odd child of a div element
div > :nth-child(3n)    every third child of a div element
```

more details click here

http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/nth-childn-css-selector/